# Show that $Ha=Hb$ if and only if $ab^{-1} \in H$ where $a,b\in G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group,  $a,b\in G$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Show that $Ha=Hb$ if and only if $ab^{-1} \in H$. 
  (Notice that $Ha$ and $Hb$ are both right cosets of $H$ by $G$).

This is what I have so far:

(-->) Suppose $Ha=Hb$. We know that $H$ is a subgroup and therefore $1_G\in H$ and from this we can derive that $a\in H$ and $b\in H$.

For a certain $h\in H$, we have:

$b\in Ha \implies b=ha \implies 1_G=h(ab^{-1})$

Is it enough to derive that $ab^{-1}\in H$ ?(because we know $1_G\in H$)

(<--) Suppose $ab^{-1} \in H$. I'm not quite sure what direction should I take from here in order to show that $Ha=Hb$. Can you please give me an hint how to start this direction?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some mistakes. If $1_G\in H$ then we cannot derive that $a\in H$ and $b\in H$.

We have that either $Hg_1=Hg_2$ or $Hg_1\cap Hg_2=\emptyset$

$(->)$

If $Ha=Hb\Rightarrow a=hb$ for some $h\in H$.

Thus $ab^{-1}=h\in H$.

$(<-)$

Let $ab^{-1}\in H$. Then $ab^{-1}=h\in H\Rightarrow a=hb=\rightarrow a\in Hb\Rightarrow Ha=Hb$.

Comment: The observation that either $Hg_1=Hg_2$ or $Hg_1\cap Hg_2=\emptyset$ is very important and helped me to understand the proof. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$$Ha=Hb$$
$$Ha\times b^{-1}=Hb\times b^{-1}$$
$$Ha\times b^{-1}=H$$

so

$$a b^{-1} \in H$$

Reverse:

$$a b ^{-1} \in H$$

$$a=h_1 b $$

$$a \in H b $$

since H is a group too:

$$Ha = H b $$

Answer (score 0):

For the converse, $ab^{-1}\in H$ implies:

1. $ab^{-1} = h_0$ for some $h_0\in H\implies a = h_0b\implies a\in Hb\implies ha \in Hb$ for every $h\in H$.

$\qquad\therefore x\in Ha\implies x\in HB$.

2. $(ab^{-1})^{-1} \in H$, by invertibility of group $H\iff ba^{-1} \in H$.

$\qquad\therefore x\in Hb\implies x\in Ha$, by applying similar argument in (1).

Hence $Ha=Hb$.

$\Box$

Comment: What exactly is the point of answering questions that have been answered years ago and have had absolutely no activity? And what is the point of adding an answer that adds absolutely nothing new or different from answers that were given over four and a half years ago?

Comment: 1. Evidently there is activity now. 2. It is absolutely nothing new or different to you; but this is a new and slightly different perspective to me that I thought worth sharing.

Comment: No, I meant it is nothing new in the context of this page; what you write is identical or almost identical to the content of answers posted here 4 years ago. Did you bother to look at them before answering? And, yes, “there’s is activity now” because *you answered*. That, in case you did not know, is called a “circular argument”. You can’t argue it’s okay to answer because there is new activity when the new activity is caused by you answering.

Comment: Yes, I read through them multiple times before answering.  I believe it suffices to share an answer as long as a reader thinks it may help or clarify, or even just to get some feedback; and should not be discouraged from doing so simply because the specific thread has been idle for a while.

Comment: Fine: here's your feedback. Your (1) is identical to the argument in the posted answer. Your (2) is utterly unnecessary, since you can obtain it **directly** from $1$ by simply exchanging the roles of $Ha$ and $Hb$. Also your (1) contains a rather obvious typo at the end. As such: your answer contains nothing new, except a  lack of realization that half of it is not needed. If you did not realize this after reading the accepted answer "mutliple times before answering", then you need to review the material again because you aren't grasping it.

Comment: For (1), the difference is that the previously posted answer went directly from $a\in Hb$ to $Ha = Hb$; whereas in my answer I expand it into the "classical" form in that in order for two sets to be considered equal, element in one set implies it is also a member in the other set and vice-versa.  (2) is just the "vice-versa" part, which is perhaps more verbose, but is technically necessary for the proof to be complete.

Comment: Your answer "expands" by forgetting **basic** properties of cosets (either disjoint or identical); that's not "classical", that's "forgetful". (2) is **unnecessary** because it follows from (1) by reversing the roles of $a$ and $b$. You wanted feedback, you got it. Don't complain if you don't like it.

Comment: Not sure how you come into the conclusion that I've forgotten anything, or how you define as the "basic" properties of cosets.  As shown above, the proof of the converse can be achieved with a simple proof, without relying on remembering.  For (2), it seems a bit terse to me to just say it follows from (1), etc. 
 Having all the steps written out explicitly makes things crystal clear.